# rails console commands are logged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a deploy production.log was deleted and then someone ran a delete_all in a Model by mistake without backing up the database, is there any place where it is logged the console output or that data is gone forever?

Edit: the database is MySql and the hosting is Amazon Beanstalk.

Comment: The log is where everything is logged.  Your db may have some logging of its own but it won't tell you who ran the query if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're in a tough spot. To prevent this sort of thing from happening in the future, consider using something like [LogEntries](https://logentries.com/product/supported-technologies/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) to record all your logs and prevent them from getting deleting by storing them off-site. LogEntries is very easy to use, but you can find further reading for MongoDB [here](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/).

Comment: Yep, all was lost :( will check your links to prevent this is future, thank you!

Comment: Aww, man! Sorry to hear that. Hopefully that won't happen again!